# How to free void array of void pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free, void-pointers

I managed to narrow my problem to this code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    void **arr;
    int max = 10; //tr = 0;
    int size = sizeof(int);

    arr = malloc(max*sizeof(void*));

    for (int i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(size);
        memcpy(arr+i, &i, size);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<=6; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(int*)(arr + i));
    }

    free(arr[0]);
    free(arr[1]);

    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

It's ok when I free `arr`, and it's ok when I free `arr[0]`. But anything other than that I get a segfault.

Am I doing the allocations wrong? Or is it something else?

Comment: `niz` undeclared. Post compilable code.

Comment: @EOF I fixed it, it's not working properly now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
for (int i=0; i<=6; i++)
{
    arr[i] = malloc(size);
    memcpy(arr[i], &i, size);
}

for (int i=0; i<=6; i++)
{
    printf("%d ", *(int*)(arr[i]));
}
```

Comment: Yes, fantastic! Can you please tell me what I was doing in the first place with my example?

Comment: @smrdo_prdo You were writing to an unintended memory. you want `*(arr+i)`, not `arr+i`. `*(arr+i)` is `arr[i]`.